# Not enough current to supply load

Tags: electricity, electric-current, voltage

Are there cases where a power supply can offer xV, which is required by a device, but be unable to supply enough current?

For example, a voltage divider not only lowers voltage, but limits the current. Wouldn't this be an issue for several components?

Comment: "Are there cases where a power supply can offer xV, which is required by a device, but be unable to supply enough current?" - Yes, like when you try to use a small iPhone charger to charge an iPad instead of using an iPad charger. Both chargers output the same voltage, but an iPhone charger can't supply as much current as an iPad charger, so it takes much longer for it to charge up an iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Power supplies are all limited by the power (voltage $\times$ current) they can supply either because there is some mechanism within the supply to limit the power (or current) which could even be a fuse or because the power supply has an internal resistance.

Comment: Ok, but in theory, a circuit with no resistance is capable of infinite current (obviously not in practise). As soon as some resistance added, the maximum current which the circuit could supply is limited. Is that correct?

Comment: And am i right in thinking that this could prove problematic for some components?

Comment: You can design circuits which output a constant voltage, ie mimic a source with zero resistance, but in the end these circuits can only supply a certain amount of power/current. There is no such thing as an infinite power source.

Comment: Could you, say, have 2 5V supplies with different current limits?

Comment: Don't forget that any real power supply also has an internal resistance, which is in series with the load. This $R_i$ will limit the current it can supply. Because of this, as well as the supply's max power output, 2 5V supplies can have different current limits.

Comment: Yes. Look at the list here. http://cpc.farnell.com/c/electrical-lighting/batteries-power-supplies/power-supplies/5v-power-supplies

Comment: @M-R, of course there are equal-voltage supplies with different current limits. Just go to any electronics distributor website and you can find 5 V regulators rated for 100 mA, or 5 V AC/DC supplies rated for 1000 W (200 A).

Comment: Just how these circuits fail when the load wants more current than they supply depends on the details of how they're made. Maybe the output voltage drops slowly. Maybe it drops very quickly (crowbar circuit). Maybe a fuse blows. Maybe the circuit just catches fire if it's poorly designed.